# Why we need to control for import and exchange rate change when examining asset growth?

Tags: econometrics, macro-economics

[Dasgupta , 2019](https://academic.oup.com/rfs/article/32/7/2587/5079300?login=true) examines the impact of antitrust laws on asset growth, total net external financing, debt-to-equity ratio. In his regression, I saw that he controls for **imports as a percentage of GDP, and the exchange rate**.

These are macro-level variable. But from macroeconomic class, I learned that there are three main macro-level variables we normally use when regressing are inflation, unemployment, and gdp. So, if I control for these three already, whether we need to control for **imports as a percentage of GDP, and the exchange rate** ?

I am wondering **why he controls for these covariates**? **Does he control these covariates because of the laws or because of the dependent variables**?

Comment: Who said this: "there are three main macro-level variables we normally use when regressing are inflation, unemployment, and gdp"

Comment: @fesman : it is from a macroeconomic course in my school for undergraduate students

Comment: Those 3 are of course important but there are many others people commonly look at including imports and FX rates. But I haven't read the article so hard to tell exactly how they chose the variables.